# Datepicker: seems constraintInput is not working in any browser?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Trying to prevent the user from manually entering a date into the input box associated with jqueries datepicker.  I just want the datepicker to populate the input box....

Heres the syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[date-picker]")
    .datepicker({ constrainInput: true });
});
```

PS:  all datetime input elements contain the  attribute: date-picker="True"

What am I missing or doing wrong??

Comment: constrainInput means entry in the input field is constrained to those characters allowed by the current dateFormat. it doesn't stop someone from typing in it.

Comment: Correction: The default behavior of setting constrainInput to true, is not happening.  The user is allowed to enter any number of digits for the date vs. only allowing the user to input the date per the default dateformat.

Comment: Again, you're misunderstanding what constrainInput does. It only limits what characters you can type in the input field. It doesn't check to see if you're entering a valid date. It stops you from typing something like !!!! but allows 98749874.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `readonly` will prevent the user from editing the input field:

```
$("input[date-picker]").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```